# No sound after upgrade to 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.10

Upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10 went fine, except no sound.  Sound shows dummy output.  While there have been many posts on similar topics, none of the solutions I have tried have worked.  All have involved CLI with terminal.  I am looking for line-by-line instructions.  Have posted on ubuntuforums, but no replies to date.

Comment: In additional to updating this question with a pointer to the other answer and the `xdg-portal` error you are seeing, you should probably link any other answers that you've tried, along with the results.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio

systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this can help?

Comment: Seems like there is a file missing named "with-pulseaudio". The touch command created this file. Why it needs this, I do not know.

After it is created we restart the service and everything works as intended.

Comment: Why do you think this file is needed?  Where did you get this from?

Comment: I cannot find the page anymore. I searched for the exact same problem, found another page telling me to do this, and it worked.

Remembered that there were other pages asking for the same thing, so I copied the answer. I see you have flagged my answer. Maybe I should delete since I have no idea why?

Comment: After recent update (to Ubuntu 22.04.2). my sound stopped working. Adding (using touch) **with-pulseaudio** fixed issue. *Need to understand why!?*