# No sound Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound

I installed ubuntu 22.10 a few months ago and since its installation the sound does not work. But if I call someone on discord from this computer he hears the sound that I can not hear. My computer is a Peaq Classic C150

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by pipewire, which is default audio service starting from Ubuntu 22.10.

### dummy output

Maybe you have noticed that there's a `dummy output` in your audio output list. If so, you can try the steps [in this post](https://www.linux.org/threads/dummy-output-ubu-22-10-please-help-im-devastated.41066/#post-164541):

```bash
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

And make sure that pulseaudio will auto start. You can set it up in *Startup Applications*.

### Otherwise

If it's still not working, you can try to look into the log of pulseaudio:

```bash
cat /var/log/syslog* | grep -i pulse
```

Comment: What does it mean when the above commands with Ubuntu 22.10 result in the cat output giving among numerous other errors, "Can't find xdg-portal". John

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have enough reputation yet to comment on the other answer here.  Normally I'd recommend that you post a separate question, but I see that [you've already done that](https://askubuntu.com/q/1444199/1165986).  Since there are no answers on your question, I'd actually recommend editing your question to include *this* question about `xdg-portal`.  That will bump it to the top of the active questions list, at least, and maybe get you pointed in the right direction.   Ironic side-note:  I was just listening to a YouTube video about XDG portals not 2 hours ago ...